# Pass Outlook addin via BHO to javascript

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, bho

I am trying to pass the Outlook addin object via VSTO C# to the embeded html page in the Internet explorer. However, it seems that the object it not properly passed as the ActiveInspector is always null. Any ideas how to fix that. The code I am using is

```
 private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
dynamic window = d.parentWindow; 
var windowEx = (IExpando)window; 
PropertyInfo p = windowEx.AddProperty("bhoModule"); 
p.SetValue(windowEx, Globals.ThiAddin.Application, null);
}
```

The javascript which receives the object is bellow

```
 $('#showInfo-button').click(function () {
        if (window.bhoModule != null) {
            window.alert("ow.bhoModule != null");

            var objOutlook = window.bhoModule.Application;
            if (objOutlook == null) {
                window.alert("objOutlook is null");
                return;
            }
            var inspector = objOutlook.ActiveInspector(); <-- NULL
            if (inspector == null) {
                window.alert("inspector is null");
                return;
            }

            var currItem = inspector.CurrentItem;
            if (currItem == null) {
                window.alert("currItem is null");
                return;
            }

            var sender = currItem.Sender;
            if (sender == null) {
                window.alert("sender is null");
                return;
            }


            $('#from').val(sender.Name);
            $('#email').val(sender.Address);
            $('#subject').val(currItem.Subject);
            $('#received').val(currItem.ReceivedTime);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you working with an item displayed in a separate inspector? Or just the currently selected item in the active explorer?

Comment: currently selected item in the active explorer. if i pass the mailitem instead of application the above code works with minor modification

Comment: Then you need to be using Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection[1]

Comment: Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection[1] is working perfectly fine on c# outlook side but when i implement it on js side curItem is always null

Comment: Use Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

Comment: Can you pls move that comment as an answer so I can accept it. This typo just saved me couple of hours of researching:) ...

Comment: Done. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` in JavaScript.